# Custom tabitem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

In WPF i want to create an custom TabItem which contains other controls.
After creating the TabItem, i want to add it to an TabControl.
The content of the TabItem will be created dynamically.

The TabItem only will be vissible after clicking on a button, and will close after entering the neccesary information.
After closing the tab, there will be no blank space in the TabControl.

I tried with a custum control, an user control and a class which inherits from an TabItem. But none of them does what i want.

Which is the best solution in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

Instead of crating an usercontrol for the tab, i created an usercontrol with the contents of the tab.
In my case, that's a grid.

After that, i use the customcontrol to fill the tabitem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the TabItem content to the UserControl not inherit from TabItem. Also you can bind the TabControl.ItemsSource to a collection of UserControls that would make it dynamic like you want I believe.